# Slim templates, format.js template rendering in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I've always worked in ERB and made heavy use of .js.erb files to render JS responses. I've recently fallen for Slim templates but I'm having a difficult time finding an equivalent to this that keeps files in the Slim format.

Assuming I'm executing the `update` action within my controller and the end looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

And let's pretend that I'm trying to just send `alert('hello')` as a response.

`update.js` works correctly and so does `update.js.erb`, naturally. If `update.js.slim` looks like this:

```
javascript:
  alert('hello')
```

...it is sent as a response that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {
  alert('hello');

}).call(this);
</script>
```

That won't work because the browser expects Javascript and that is an HTML file with script tags. Thanks, Slim. It DOES work if I use `|` to render plain text:

**update.js.slim**

```
| 
  alert('hi');
```

Everything after the pipe character shows up in SublimeText 2 color-coded and I still get access to Ruby code and variables within `#{}`. So far, this seems like my best and only option if I want to insist on keeping things in Slim format, but since it doesn't give me any of the benefits of Slim, I almost feel like just using `.js.erb` for these files might be better, since it has native support for this sort of thing.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried using the `plain:` directive instead of `javascript:`?

Comment: @DamienRoche I'm not sure what gave you the indication I wasn't using unobtrusive JS? I use JS templates to handle responses to `remote: true` AJAX calls. I was using `alert('hello')` as a simple example.

Comment: @Iceman No! I didn't know that existed. I can't find it anywhere in the documentation, can you link me?

Comment: @subvertallchris Well, I use it in Haml and it works great, I just figured it was available for Slim too, maybe it doesn't...

Comment: @Iceman Ah, I see. Yeah, I found I can use `|` and it does the trick. Was just seeing if there was a better way, though I can't imagine what that would look like within the template.

Comment: @DamienRoche What structure do you mean? Obtrusive JS or the use of JS templates?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the use of the returning JS templates instead of using events. You return a template because it has something specific to that request -- instead, why not make a request, respond with data, hook into success event, and run appropriate code?

Comment: @DamienRoche I think you're getting too hung up on my `alert('hello')` example. If I want to run a bit of JavaScript, I write JavaScript. If I want to submit a form with AJAX and then update the view based on the controller's action, I use a JS template. It's a very Rails-y way of doing things: user submits form from view to controller, controller does its job and renders a JS template. It's completely analogous to the same behavior when using traditional erb/haml/slim/etc,... templates.

Comment: @DamienRoche But of course, it depends on what I am trying to accomplish. There are times where handling the AJAX request purely through JS and bypassing JS templates is appropriate, but not always. If we're just talking converting what would be traditional browser behavior (post this form, get this link, etc,...) I think JS templates make perfect sense. Rails provides `remote: true` and JS templates specifically so we don't have to reinvent the wheel and handle AJAX requests manually.

Comment: Most probably getting my wires crossed! But, still, something more close to your actual code would help.

Comment: @DamienRoche That link you posted is exactly what I am describing and how I typically use JS templates. My example is fine, though, since my problem was that the code in the template wasn't being executed. It doesn't matter what the code is in my example -- `alert('hello')` or `$("post-<%= @post.id %>").html("<p><%= @post.body %></p>")` -- since neither of them would have executed without using `|` as in my last example. @Iceman confirmed that `|` is probably the best way of going about it, there really isn't much more here to say.

Comment: @subvertallchris as I say, I was most definitely getting my wires crossed. I thought you were using RJS at first.

Comment: @subvertallchris just read your article on Torquebox! Very helpful. Been meaning to use it myself lately. I won't sidetrack this question much further, but did you use it in development, too? I found JRuby to be mind-numbingly slow in dev (mainly tests, even with nailgun and a drb server), but use JRuby/Puma in production.

Comment: @DamienRoche Ah! Cool, I'm glad someone actually read that! I almost always used WEBrick in dev, only really used Torquebox in dev when I was testing caching. I tried to find ways to speed it up but working with it in dev was a really unpleasant experience, no matter what I did. Torquebox in production has been great but I can't say I have much to compare it to. I'd probably enjoy it more if I wasn't using Neo4j.rb 2.3, since it puts some restrictions on things.

Comment: @subvertallchris I've found WEBrick to be excruciatingly slow, even in dev. Could have been my local config. Thin, in comparison, was much faster (as is Puma). I've heard Torquebox is great as a complete architecture, background jobs, caching, etc. Without it, you'd have to manage those processes yourself (memcache, sidekiq, app servers), which are usually managed via Foreman. I might give another shot. There is little discussion about Torquebox in the blogoshere, so it was pleasant to see your post.

Comment: @DamienRoche That's really good to know! I'll have to try Thin and Puma when I get back to working with JRuby. The lack of discussion about Torquebox and hosting Rails JRuby apps in general was a real stumbling block for me. I come from a traditional HTML/PHP-on-Apache/IIS background and hosting Rails was complicated enough on its own before the JVM even got involved! When the smoke cleared, I wanted to put something up to show that it's harder to find resources that describe the process than it is to actually implement it.